# Why does intellij not accept this scala code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

The following code is compiling just fine with nsc:

```
trait A {
  type B[+T]
  type C[+T] <: B[T]
  def c: C[Int]
}

object Q {
  val a: A = ???
  val b: a.B[Int] = a.c
}
```

but intellij doesn't accept it with the error message

> expression of type `Q.a.C[Int]` doesn't conform to expected type `Q.a.B[Int]`

Why is this the case? Is it defined somewhere what subset of Scala is allowed in IntelliJ?

Comment: can you try doing this: import scala.language.higherKinds    I get this as warnings in the repl. Maybe that could fix this.

Comment: Does the file fail to compile when you build the project, or is it just highlighted as an error? In the second case, this just happens with IDEA (both ways): report it (after making sure it isn't a duplicate).

Comment: no, that doesn't solve the problem. Note, that I'm talking about IntelliJ's syntax highlighting/code completion, not the normal compiling

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov where do I report this?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reporting-issues-and-sharing-your-feedback.html

Comment: created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10692 let's see what happens